# Powershell Scheduled Task Restart Every Hour if Fails

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I want to write a powershell script that creates a scheduled task in Windows, but if it fails, it will try again in an hour. Essentially, I want the equivalent of these boxes:

[image]

How would I modify the code below to be able to control those parameters?

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'aggregate.pyw'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 4:30am
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Auto aggregate"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RestartCount**

Specifies the number of times that Task Scheduler attempts to restart the task.

**RestartInterval**

Specifies the amount of time that Task Scheduler attempts to restart the task.

**StartWhenAvailable**

Indicates that Task Scheduler can start the task at any time after its scheduled time has passed.

You can browse all the other `New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet` parameters  [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasksettingsset?view=win10-ps)

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'aggregate.pyw'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 4:30am
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -RestartCount:3 -RestartInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 60) -StartWhenAvailable
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Auto aggregate" -Settings $settings
```

[image]